# Desgin View Is Not Showing On Visual Studio-2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project using Visual Basic(Programming language)on Visual Studio-2017 and when i first start my projects i get my design view like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLwGn.png),

Then when i save my work and re-open the project another time my desgin view is not showing up and it looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s71sn.png)

Please help!! My desgin view apperars when i start a new project and when i save the project and come back to it another time it's not showing up and i don't how to get it back  and i searched all over the internet i can't find an answer. I tired lot of methods  to bring the design view back but it's just brings up the code like in the 2nd image. Please help!

Comment: If you have a question about Visual Studio, there is no need to tag `vba` as it has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: You're better off only tagging the correct version too instead of all of them.

Comment: Sorry it was the auto filling option that done that i will take it off!

Comment: I think second time you opened in folder view

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain more pelease!

Comment: close project and open again clicking on solution file .sln

Comment: Oh ok i get it. Probelm solved. So when Visual Studio-2017 starts you have to open your project from (Open Project/Solution) not (Open Folder). What a silly mistake i made. I was going crazy and no one had the answer except "Alexan". Stackoverflow is really good.

Comment: I done it and it's working TOTALLY fine. Thank you! "Alexan"

Comment: "Alexan" your way worked as well. But then i just figured out the other way, the normal way.  (Open Project/Solution) not (Open Folder) when Visual Studio-2017 starts and bring up the start page. I can't believe i was thinking some advanced stuff for a simple thing. WOW!

Comment: added answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can open project in VS 2017 by two ways: open folder where files are located or open solution: .sln file:

[image: VS Open]

Open solution give you some advantages, for example you can see compile, debug and as in this case see form design view.

Answer (score 0):

@aace2030 I have face the same issue with VS 2017, but I was able to solve it. What you got to do is right click on your form, for example if your form name is "Form1.cs". Right click on it and you'll see an option called "Include in project", just click on it, this should solve your problem.